# ErrorException Array to string conversion-Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to upload files on my laravel project but getting an error
'ErrorException Array to string conversion'

Any help will be much appreciated. Below is the error

ErrorException Array to string conversion

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\filesUpload\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:609

```php
    /**
     * Replace a given value in the string sequentially with an array.
     *
     * @param  string  $search
     * @param  array<int|string, string>  $replace
     * @param  string  $subject
     * @return string
     */

    public static function replaceArray($search, array $replace, $subject) 
    {
        $segments = explode($search, $subject);
        $result = array_shift($segments);

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment; //line 609
        }
 
        return $result;
    }
```

[image: line 609]

Comment: I would start with some echo's (or write to file) to try and debug what is being passed in and then you have a chance of debugging.

Comment: Can you share the code of the controller method for the `survey/store` endpoint ?